# I tried do install tidyversepackage and received the message

Tags: r

```
> library(tidyverse)
Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’
```

I tried to configure R Studio

Answer (score 0):

`library(tidyverse)` is for loading the package after installation. For you to install the package run `install.packages("tidyverse")`